# Passing GoogleMapsAPI camera change through segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, segue

So I've created a Google Map with about 10 different markers on it in a View Controller (ViewControllerX). All of the markers are placed according to lat/long coordinates being pulled from a MySQL database.

Now I also have a TableView (ViewControllerY) that shows users a list of nearby markers. When they click on a location in the tableview, it takes them to a detail view controller that displays information about the location. That said, I've added a button in the DetailViewController that says, "Show On Map".

Naturally, when users click this button, I want it to push them to the MapView controller (ViewControllerX) and zoom in on the corresponding marker.

I feel like this should be easy, but it's driving me nuts. Here's the segue I'm using in my DetailViewController, and the code that's on the receiving end (in my GoogleMapViewController).

***My question:*** Does anyone know what code I need to place inside of the DetailViewController segue & GoogleMapViewController to make the camera zoom in to my specific set of coordinates on the map?

**DetailViewController.m**

```
- (IBAction)showonMap:(id)sender {

    UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_1" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *initViewController = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"GoogleViewController"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:initViewController animated:YES];


    }
```

**GoogleViewController.m (google map)**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

  GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:49.282237
                                                            longitude:-123.125966
                                  zoom:13];

    mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];

    self.view = mapView;

    for (NSDictionary *dictionary in array) {
        assert([dictionary respondsToSelector:@selector(objectForKey:)]);

        CLLocationCoordinate2D position = {[[dictionary objectForKey:@"lat"] doubleValue],
            [[dictionary objectForKey:@"lng"] doubleValue]};
          NSLog(@"%f", position.longitude);

        GMSMarker *ann = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
        ann.title = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Name"];
        ann.snippet = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Address1"];
        ann.position = position;
        ann.map = mapView;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're searching for [`setVisibleMapRect:animated:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MKMapView/setVisibleMapRect%3aanimated%3a) method which will zoom to the given [`MKMapRect`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKitDataTypesReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/MKMapSize).

You can create the `MKMapRect` using the function `MKMapRectMake`, based on the marker position as its center and a width and height, depending on the level of zoom you wish.

Hope it will work for you.